AMP template can not be shown in Gmail web based
AMP template shows errors of displaying the dynamic content with the error code of INVALID_AMP. enter image description here
I tried some validation tools (AMP playground, AMP web based validator) - all of them are showing pass results but the AMP still shown error on Gmail website in Chrome browser.
enter image description here

Instead of that latter screen-dump showing the browser debugger, could you please post a minimal example of code that reproduces the problem and post it in a pre-formatted text block? (delimited by triple-back-ticks)
